# Converting pixels in grayscale image to black (OpenCV) causes unexpected result?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to manually mask an image so that only a circular area of the image is visible. I've attempted to accomplish this by specifying the center of the circle and the radius- The distance from the center to each pixel in the image, and if that distance is greater than the radius, I turn that pixel black.

My input image is all white (for testing purposes), and is 6000x4000 px.
The center is (3224,2032) and radius is 1810 px.

After processing it, I get this poorly masked image

[image]

Here, the blue circle is the area I expected not to be changed: Expected Result

[image]

What is going on??

Edit: I switched the indices for xMax and yMax. The change yielded this result

[image]

```
import cv2
def mask (img, Xcenter, Ycenter, radius):
    radius2 = float(radius**2.00)
    Xcenter = float(Xcenter)
    Ycenter = float(Ycenter)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    imgSize = img.shape
    xMax = imgSize[0]
    yMax = imgSize[1]

    print("Drawing mask...")

    for y in range(1,yMax):
        for x in range(1,xMax):
            dist2 = int(((x - Xcenter)**2 + (y - Ycenter)**2))
            try:
                if dist2 >= radius2:
                    img[x, y] = 0
            except IndexError:
                pass
                #print ("Index error: X = ", x, " Y = ", y)
                #char = input("Press enter to continue")
    cv2.imwrite("maskedImg.tif", img)
    print("Completed mask.")
    return img
```

Answer (score 0):

.shape returns the number of rows/columns/channels of the image.

.size returns the number of pixels.

These are most likely going to be different, so when you reference pixels with the circle function, they don't line up as you'd expect.

Comment: imgSize is my variable, defined as img.shape. It's redundant, but I liked the sound of size better than shape.

Comment: Is the radius variable you are passing in pixels? Because the xMax and yMax values are going to be arbitrary integers. Your image might be 6000x4000 pixels but only contain 600x400 rows/columns (not sure what actual numbers might be). So when you compare dist2 >= radius2 you are not actually comparing pixel vs. pixel.

Comment: The radius is also in pixels. Also I don't see how x and yMax are arbitrary- they represent the image shape. Sorta like how you can specify the canvas size when you make a new file in photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've mixed up x and y. Number of "rows" would be Y, so

```
yMax = imgSize[0]
xMax = imgSize[1]
```

Remember, point (0,0) is top left.
Also, for testing, I’d suggest putting your circle in the centre first. It doesn’t REALLY matter but sometimes you can debug these things more easily in pictures.

Comment: I've tried many combinations of x and y in an attempt to fix it, but nothing worked how I wanted it to. I tried your suggestion- I put the resulting image in the original question. In that image, the white bar on the right side is where I got index errors that I let pass.

Comment: Hmm, switching those has rotated your black background. How about switching Xcenter and Ycenter (rest of the code as in your original question)? And where does it put the circle with centre (0,0)?

Comment: You’re almost there because you have a circle shape. I think if you look at circles with centre (0,0) (3000,0), (0,2000) And (6000,4000) you might be able to fix it.